# MySQL echo groups with unique value PHP

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I apologize if there are similar questions...I had trouble finding them! What I would like to do is select some rows in a database, and then fetch them, but echo them in groups based on unique rows. Let me explain with an example (I have omitted some things for brevity):

I have a select query like this:

```
SELECT
    e.exercisename ExerciseName,
    eh.reps Reps,
    eh.weight Weight
FROM workouts w
JOIN users u ON w.userid = u.id
JOIN workouts_history wh ON w.id = wh.workoutid
JOIN exercises e ON wh.exerciseid = e.id
JOIN exercises_history eh ON wh.id = eh.workouts_historyid
```

Right now, this gives me a table based off of this while:

```
while($workoutrowridge = $workoutresultridge->fetch_assoc()) {
    $workoutoutputridge .= '<tr>';
        $workoutoutputridge .= '<td>'.$workoutrowridge['ExerciseName'].'</td>';
        $workoutoutputridge .= '<td>'.$workoutrowridge['Reps'].'</td>';
        $workoutoutputridge .= '<td>'.$workoutrowridge['Weight'].'</td>';               
    $workoutoutputridge .= '</tr>';
}
```

that looks like this:

```
Exercise    | Reps | Weight
---------------------------
Squats      |   8  |  135
Squats      |   8  |  225
Squats      |   6  |  315
Squats      |   2  |  405
Squats      |   1  |  485
Bench (DB)  |   8  |  60
Bench (DB)  |   6  |  80
Bench (DB)  |   4  |  90
Bench (DB)  |   2  |  95
Pullup      |   4  |  0
Pullup      |   3  |  25
Pullup      |   1  |  45
Pullup      |   1  |  70
```

What I would like to happen though, is to have a new table echoed for each unique 'ExerciseName' (for example). A workout may have only 1 exercise, or it may have 20, with a different amount of sets for each one, like this:

```
Exercise    | Reps | Weight
---------------------------
Squats      |   8  |  135
Squats      |   8  |  225
Squats      |   6  |  315
Squats      |   2  |  405
Squats      |   1  |  485

Exercise    | Reps | Weight
---------------------------
Bench (DB)  |   8  |  60
Bench (DB)  |   6  |  80
Bench (DB)  |   4  |  90
Bench (DB)  |   2  |  95
```

I feel like there is a way to keep this as one query, and just use some type of foreach in the PHP to do this...but I have been unable to get this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if the query result is sorted by the `ExerciseName` I would do it like this

this is your loop , I will just add couple of lines

```
$lastExercise = ""; // my edit
while($workoutrowridge = $workoutresultridge->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($workoutrowridge['ExerciseName'] != $lastExercise ){
         $workoutoutputridge .= "<tr><td>Exercise</td><td>Reps</td><td>Weight</td></tr>";
    }
    $lastExercise = $workoutrowridge['ExerciseName'];

//the rest is your original code
    $workoutoutputridge .= '<tr>';
         $workoutoutputridge .= '<td>'.$workoutrowridge['ExerciseName'].'</td>';
         $workoutoutputridge .= '<td>'.$workoutrowridge['Reps'].'</td>';
         $workoutoutputridge .= '<td>'.$workoutrowridge['Weight'].'</td>';               
    $workoutoutputridge .= '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: That is a good solution, thanks. I am going to accept the other answer as the correct one as it was the first response. But I will still give you a vote for this answer.

Comment: @RidgeRobinson it's ok I just wanted to help,  you are polite :) , yes his answer come before mien :)

Answer (score 4):

you could do something like this :

```
$currentExercise = '';
echo '<table>';
while($workoutrowridge = $workoutresultridge->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($currentExercise !== '' && $workoutoutputridge['ExerciseName'] !== $currentExercise) {
        echo '</table><table>';
    }
    $workoutoutputridge .= '<tr>';
    $workoutoutputridge .= '<td>'.$workoutrowridge['ExerciseName'].'</td>';
    $workoutoutputridge .= '<td>'.$workoutrowridge['Reps'].'</td>';
    $workoutoutputridge .= '<td>'.$workoutrowridge['Weight'].'</td>';
    $workoutoutputridge .= '</tr>';

    $currentExercise = $workoutrowridge['ExerciseName'];
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: That's a great solution...so simple. I am not sure why I didn't think of that...I was trying to be much more complex, sometimes the easy way is the best!

Comment: Yes, you also could have created a new array with another sub-level for exercises names

Answer (score 2):

[edit]
without the empty `<table>` if you don't have any exercise

---

For something clean you can use this :

```
$currentEx = false;

while($workoutrowridge = $workoutresultridge->fetch_assoc()) {

    if(!$currentEx) // first round
        $workoutoutputridge .= "<table>\n";
    else if($currentEx AND $workoutrowridge['ExerciseName'] != $currentEx){
        $workoutoutputridge .= "</table>\n";
        $workoutoutputridge .= "<table>\n";
        $currentEx = $workoutrowridge['ExerciseName'];
    }

    $workoutoutputridge .= "<tr>\n";
    $workoutoutputridge .=      "<td>".$workoutrowridge['ExerciseName']."</td>\n";
    $workoutoutputridge .=      "<td>".$workoutrowridge['Reps']."</td>\n";
    $workoutoutputridge .=      "<td>".$workoutrowridge['Weight']."</td>\n";         
    $workoutoutputridge .= "</tr>\n";

}

if($workoutoutputridge)
    $workoutoutputridge .= "</table>\n";
```

Comment: *"For something clean you can use this"* - Actually, for something even "cleaner" and in order to avoid having the HTML source come out looking as one big clump of code on one line, adding `"\n"` after each element will produce clean HTML; a worthy method when it comes to having to debug through (HTML) source ;-) Using HTML source is just as good a "tool" in (web) development.

Comment: @Fred-ii- space, \t and \n take space on network, any debug tool make auto-indent now, worrying about a "clean html" is a bit useless over a clean php file, take a look at the google source code XD ; but you can put `."\n"` at the end, yes.

Comment: *"any debug tool make auto-indent now"* - I myself don't rely on browser debug tools. They're good, don't get me wrong. But say someone wants to grab source from scraping, that's another story. I always add `"\n"`'s to all my code, regardless.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes I usually do the same, even if when I'm working on M2M, I now use JSON without the PRETTY_PRINT and go for online validator.